# Compare neighbours boolean numpy array in grid

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to write a function which compares the 8 neighbours of a node in my grid. When minimum of 3 of the neighbours have the same value as the central node, we can define the node as happy.

for example in this array the central node and value is 0, we see that it has 3 neighbours of 0, so the node is happy:

```
 array([[ 1,  0,  1],
       [ 1,  0,  1],
       [-1,  0,  0]])
```

I expect an boolean output with `True` or `False`.

Can I think of something like this or can I use easily numpy for this?

```
def nodehappiness(grid, i, j, drempel=3):
    if i,j => 3:
       node == True
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for something along the lines of scipy's `ndimage.generic_filter(arr, f, footprint=footprint, mode='wrap')`? [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10998027/365102).

Comment: Also relevant: `np.pad(arr, pad_width=1, mode='wrap')`

Comment: numpy indexing actually allows you to use `-1` as an index for the last entry. That way you don`t need to use functions like `generic_filter` or `pad`

Comment: Is the order of the result list relevant?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def neighbours(grid, i, j):
    rows = np.array([-1, -1, -1,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1])
    cols = np.array([-1,  0,  1, -1,  1, -1,  0,  1])
    return grid[rows+i,cols+j]
```

Edit: **Example**:

```
grid = np.arange(25).reshape((5,5))
#array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
#       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
#       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
#       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
#       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])

neighbours(grid, 0, 0)
# array([24, 20, 21,  4,  1,  9,  5,  6])
```

**Explanation**:

With `numpy` you can use negative indices allowing you to easily access the last entries of an array. This will also work for multiple dimensions:

```
x = np.array([0,1,2,3])
x[-1]
# 3

x.reshape((2,2))
#array([[0, 1],
#       [2, 3]])

x[-1,-1]
# 3
```

You are interested in 8 entries of the matrix.

1. left above -> row - 1, column - 1
2. above      -> row - 1, column + 0
3. right above -> row - 1, column + 1
4. left -> row + 0, column - 1
5. ...

Thats what the arrays `rows` and `cols` represent. By adding `i` and `j` you get all the entries around these coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need a global function which I can use for each grid. It needs to wrap every grid I define

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. You can call my `neighbours` function on any 2d-grid.

Comment: I don't understand your code. Because it doesnt give my expected result. What are you doing with the np.array in the rows and cols? I dont get my expected results. Can you please explain your code?

Comment: Sure, I will edit and explain. Just to clarify, could you tell me what the expected result would be in my example?

Comment: No I get now the expected result, thanks in advance! But can you explain what you've done?

Comment: Ok, I will add an explanation

Answer (score 0):

You search something like this?

```
def neighbour(grid, i, j):
    return np.delete((grid[i-1:i+2,j-1:j+2]).reshape(1,9),4)

# Test code
grid = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)

b = neighbour(m, 2, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
y=[]
l= len(x)
for i in range(0,l):
    for j in range(0,l):
        if i==int(l/2) and j==int(l/2):
            continue
        y.append(x[j,i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Some hackery using [`ndimage.generic_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter.html):

```
from scipy import ndimage

def get_neighbors(arr):
    output = []
    def f(x):
        output.append(x)
        return 0

    t = tuple(int((x - 1) / 2) for x in arr.shape)
    footprint = np.ones_like(arr)
    footprint[t] = 0
    ndimage.generic_filter(arr, f, footprint=footprint, mode='wrap')
    return np.array(output)

arr = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
neighbors = get_neighbors(arr)
neighbors_grid = neighbors.reshape(*arr.shape, -1)

print(neighbors)
print(neighbors_grid)
```

Which prints:

```
# neighbors
[[8. 6. 7. 2. 1. 5. 3. 4.]
 [6. 7. 8. 0. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
 [7. 8. 6. 1. 0. 4. 5. 3.]
 [2. 0. 1. 5. 4. 8. 6. 7.]
 [0. 1. 2. 3. 5. 6. 7. 8.]
 [1. 2. 0. 4. 3. 7. 8. 6.]
 [5. 3. 4. 8. 7. 2. 0. 1.]
 [3. 4. 5. 6. 8. 0. 1. 2.]
 [4. 5. 3. 7. 6. 1. 2. 0.]]

# neighbors_grid
[[[8. 6. 7. 2. 1. 5. 3. 4.]
  [6. 7. 8. 0. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
  [7. 8. 6. 1. 0. 4. 5. 3.]]

 [[2. 0. 1. 5. 4. 8. 6. 7.]
  [0. 1. 2. 3. 5. 6. 7. 8.]
  [1. 2. 0. 4. 3. 7. 8. 6.]]

 [[5. 3. 4. 8. 7. 2. 0. 1.]
  [3. 4. 5. 6. 8. 0. 1. 2.]
  [4. 5. 3. 7. 6. 1. 2. 0.]]]
```

If you merely want the padded array:

```
padded = np.pad(arr, pad_width=1, mode='wrap')
print(padded)
```

Which of course gives:

```
[[8 6 7 8 6]
 [2 0 1 2 0]
 [5 3 4 5 3]
 [8 6 7 8 6]
 [2 0 1 2 0]]
```