# Get neighboring values from an element in 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to extract the neighbors of an element in a 2D array. This seems like a simple function but I was unable to find one in numpy. My current solution is this but I wonder if there is a better way?

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
import operator


def get_neighbors(a, coord):
  # exclude element itself
  indices = [p for p in itertools.product([-1,0,1],[-1,0,1]) if p != (0,0)]

  x = []
  y = []
  for i in indices:
    c = tuple(map(operator.add, coord, i))
    if c[0] >= 0 and c[0] < a.shape[0] and c[1] >= 0 and c[1] < a.shape[1]:
      x.append(c[0])
      y.append(c[1])

  # fancy indexing
  return a[x,y]


a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
print(get_neighbors(a, (2,2)))
```

After some time I got a good solution with:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage

def test_func(values):
  print(values, type(values))
  return 1


x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

footprint = np.array([[1,1,1],
                      [1,0,1],
                      [1,1,1]])

results = ndimage.generic_filter(x, test_func, footprint=footprint,
  mode='constant', cval=np.nan)
print(x)
print(results)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pixel neighbors in 2d array (image) using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996769/pixel-neighbors-in-2d-array-image-using-python)

Comment: I did take a look at this answer and the most upvoted is scipy's generic_filter(). But I don't get how it works or what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use a mask.

```
def get_neighbors(a, r, c):
    mask = np.zeros(a.shape,dtype=bool)
    mask[r-1 if r!=0 else r:r+2,c-1 if c!=0 else c:c+2] = True 
    mask[r,c] = False 
    return a[mask]
```

A more efficient answer without any masks can be done if you define a simple constant. There are at most 9 pixels, whenever we slice the center pixel and the neighbors, and it's trivial to determine which one is the center pixel among the sliced indices.

```
POSITION_CONST = np.array([[0,1,1],[2,3,4]])

def get_neighbors(a, r, c):
    C = POSITION_CONST[int(r!=0), (c!=0)*(1+int(c!=(a.shape[1]-1)))]
    N = a[max(r-1,0):r+2,max(c-1,0):c+2].ravel()
    return N[np.where(np.arange(len(N))!=C)[0]]
```

Comment: This is interesting but once the shape is huge it might be inefficient? Meaning the mask is full of False.

Comment: @chhenning I think the answer with generic_filter is absolute bollocks. We simply want to extract only N-1 pixels from the image, where N is at most 9 and at least 4. Moreover, these pixels are adjacent. A slice should be enough to do this; and computing the position of the varying center is pretty simple, since the center pixel is always in positions 0 to 4! See my updated answer and consider accepting it. It runs nearly thrice as fast as generic_filter.

Comment: I did some timing and the generic_filter is faster than your proposal. In my test app your solution would take 32secs while the generic_filter takes 26 secs. Also is the code much more readable, meaning less cryptic. But thanks for your input, I learned more about numpy which is the greater goal.

Comment: Strange, but alright, thanks.